# Ruby on Rails 5 + ActionCable + Puma + Nginx で Puma をソケットで起動すると WebSocket に接続できないのは仕様でしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

タイトルの通りですが、 Rails 5 + ActionCable + Puma + Nginx で Puma をソケットで起動すると WebSocket に接続できないのは仕様でしょうか？

主な利用バージョンは下記の通りです。

- Ruby: 2.4.2
- Ruby on Rails: 5.0.6
- Puma: 3.11.2
- Nginx: 1.12.2

例えば、 Puma は `bundle exec puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:9292` のように起動して、 Nginx の設定は下記のように書くと、 WebSocket に接続できることを確認しました。

```
server {
    location /websocket {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9292;
    }
}
```

これを、 Puma は `bundle exec puma -b unix:///var/run/puma.sock` のように起動して、 Nginx の設定は下記のように書くと、 WebSocket に接続できませんでした。

```
server {
    location /websocket {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/puma.sock;
    }
}
```

そこでお伺いしたのですが、

- これは WebSocket （または ActionCable ？）の仕様でしょうか？

  - 仕様である場合、仕様が書かれたドキュメントがあればご教示いただきたいです。
- もしくは、 Puma や Nginx の設定の書き方や起動方法が間違っているだけで、 Puma をソケットで起動しても WebSocket に接続できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 下記のサイトを参考にシンプルな構成の Ruby on Rails 5 + ActionCable + Puma + Nginx を作ってみたところ、 WebSocket で接続できることを確認しました。

https://qiita.com/port-development/items/120b2bee0cef505a4005

ですので、この構成で WebSocket に接続できない、ということは無いようです。

Comment: 私が構築したい環境は冗長化を行っており、アプリサーバーとは別にプロキシサーバーがあり、 nginx （プロキシサーバー） -> nginx （アプリサーバー） -> puma.sock というで、 WebSocket に接続ができないです。引き続き情報をお待ちしております。